# When background-size is set to contain, image is displayed much smaller and not stretched

Tags: html, css, background-size

When `background-size: 100%;` is used I get the behaviour I want, but I don't understand why when I try `background-size: contain;` my Chrome browser shows the image tucked up in the corner, only about 20% of the browser window width. Firefox does the same.

[www.moonwards.com](http://moonwards.com/)

```
body {
background: url(http://www.moonwards.com/img/tycho.png);
background-size: contain;
background-color: #000;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Why is that happening? [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) says these browsers shouldn't have trouble with this.

Comment: Is the image in question the same size exactly as the displayed container element? The `contain` value is designed to maintain the image's aspect ratio so if there is a difference in sizes you will see a "letterbox" effect. Keep in mind the "height" attribute on the document body is a very sketchy thing.

Comment: Your body is only as high as the content, around 160px.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz oh, I thought it responded to the window size. Alright then, I just wanted to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `background: url(http://link);` Simply, try this,

> ```
>     body {
>         margin: 0 auto;
>         background-image: url(http:link);
>     }
> ```

This works for me.  However, I also download the image and place it in the same folder as my Website.  I also find myself using Photoshop quite a bit to size images and to control quality.